# How to save a VF page rendered as PDF to Notes and Attachments?

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

My requirement is to store a VF page rendered as Pdf to Notes and Attachments,My VF Page is being used by a custom button ,and code is as follows :

Visualforce Page :

```
<apex:page StandardController="Quote__c" showHeader="false"  renderAs="pdf" extensions="QuoteAsPDFController" action="{!attach}"> 

     <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AdvancedPDFResources, 'qstyles.css')}"/> 

    <table width="100%" >
        <tr width="100%">
            <td width="100%" align="left">
                <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AdvancedPDFResources, 'logo.gif')}"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="100%" align="center">
                 <apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%" styleClass="quoteinfo">
                    <b><apex:outputText value="Quote#: {!Quote__c.name}" /></b>
                    <b><apex:outputField value="{!Quote__c.lastmodifieddate}" style="text-align:right"/></b>
                    <!--<apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Opportunity_Name__c.Account_Name__c.name}" />-->
                    <apex:outputText value="" />
                </apex:panelGrid>
            </td>
           </tr>

        </table>
                        <b>Prepared For :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; <apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Contact_Name__c}"/><br/>
                        <b>Bill To :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Bill_To_Name__c}"/><br/>
                        <b>Description : </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Description__c}"/><br/>
                        <b>Status :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Status__c}"/><br/>
                        <b>Quote Number :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Quote_Number__c}"/><br/>
                        <b>Phone :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Phone__c}"/><br/>
                        <b>Email :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Email__c}"/><br/>
                        <b>Fax :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Quote__c.Fax__c}"/><br/>    


</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller :

```
public with sharing class QuoteAsPDFController {
    public String QuoteId;
    public QuoteAsPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    QuoteId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    }
    public void attach() {
        Attachment myAttach = new Attachment();
        myAttach.ParentId = QuoteId;//Id of the object to which the page is attached
        myAttach.name = 'Quotation.pdf';
        PageReference myPdf = ApexPages.currentPage();//myPdfPage is the name of your pdf page
        myAttach.body = myPdf.getContentAsPdf();
        insert myAttach;
    }
}
```

But the code is not working find,and could not identify the function attach().

Error Message :

[image]

Pls help.

Comment: What is the error message you receive?  Can you please update the question with it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update page parameter

```
 action="{!attach()}"
```

to

```
 action="{!attach}"
```

Then it will create the record.

Comment: Its showing Error as :" Too many nested getContent calls"

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena the problem here is you are referring same page from action . So its type of recursive loop situation. So I suggest use another page and then call that page from this page action attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `action` attribute on the `apex:page` component to create the pdf.  As per the docs:

> This method will be called before the page is rendered and allows you to optionally redirect the user to another page. This action should not be
>   used for initialization.

From my understanding, this means the constructor won't be called until after `attach()` has run.

You might have to do this as a 2 stage process:

1. User clicks a button that takes them to the VF page.  This can be thought of as the preview
2. User then clicks a button on the VF page that calls your `attach()` method, which then attaches the PDF to the quote

Comment: But a VF page rendered as PDF does not displays Buttons

Comment: The page they go to in step 1 won't be a PDF.  It's a regular VF page.  I can't think of a way to do this off the top of my head.  Just pointing out the problem you're currently facing.

Comment: @NickCook constructor will always call first then this attach method.